# How was the relationship between Rama and Shatrughna?

Tags: ramayana, rama

As per Ramayana, Rama had 3 named brothers, Bharata, Lakshmana and Shatrughna.

When Rama is exiled, Bharata goes to Rama and asks him to come back to Ayodhya but Rama refuses. Though deeply disappointed, Bharata returned to Ayodhya after receiving a promise from Rama that he would return promptly at the end of the fourteen-year exile and ascend the throne.

As per Hanuman Chalisa verse, तुम मम प्रिय भरतहि सम भाई (meaning, You are as dear to me as my brother Bharata) which clearly shows deep Love between Rama and Bharata.

Lakshman is the younger brother of Rama and close companion of the god Rama, Lakshman serves Rama and Sita reverently during the exile.

Lakshmana is especially attached to Rama, and when Rama marries Sita, Lakshmana marries Sita's younger sister Urmila. Later, when Rama goes on exile for fourteen years on the insistence of Kaikeyi, Lakshmana leaves his wife Urmila and joins Rama.

Lakshman also built hut for Rama and Sita to live in Panchvati, as per [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshmana) Link.

This indicates how close and dear Lakshman was to Rama.

Is there a similar incident/occasion in Ramayana that shows Love/closeness between Rama and Shatrughna?

How was the relationship between Rama and Shatrughna?

Comment: I think that Lord Shatrugna was to Lord Bharata what Lord Laksamana was to Lord Rama. He sincerely loved all His brothers but His love for Bharata was unparalleled.

Comment: Dasaratha had over 350 wives. We can safely assume Rama has more brothers.

Comment: In case you are wondering why he did not before Rama, that can easily be explained by him wanting his heir to be special.

Answer (score 1):

Shatrughna was the twin brother of Lakshmana, ie, he and Lakshama were born by Sumitra. Although, he was more inclined towards Bharat but still he also had good relations with Lord Rama and Lakshama. This can be seen from the fact that he tried to kill Manthara on knowing that she has provoked Kaikeyi to send Lord Rama on exile. Later, on Kaikeyi's request, Bharat stopped him saying that killing a women won't be acceptable to Lord Rama. As per [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatrughna):

> Manthara appears only once in the Ramayan after Rama's banishment. Having been rewarded by Kaikeyi with costly clothing and jewels, she is walking in the palace gardens when Bharata and his half-brother Shatrughna come upon her. Seeing her, Shatrughna flies into a violent rage over Rama's banishment and assaults her murderously. Kaikeyi begs Bharata to save her, which he does, telling Shatrughna that it is a sin to kill a woman and that Rama would be furious with them both if he does such a thing. He relents and the brothers leave, while Kaikeyi attempts to comfort Manthara.

Shatrughna also went along with Bharat to bring Lord Rama and Lakshmana back to Ayodhya. When they refused coming back, Bharat was supposed to be the king but Bharat instead placed Lord Rama's Charan-paduka on throne and started living in a hut on the banks of Sarayu river. It was Shatrughna at that time, who was actually looking after the administration of the kingdom.

Also, he is supposed to be the reincarnation of Vishnu's sacred Conch and when Lord Rama completed his lifetime on earth and submerged in River Sarayu to return to his eternal MahaVishnu form, Shartughana and Bharat also followed him by submerging at the same time thus merging into MahaVishnu..

Comment: Although your reference hints at close relationship between Rama and  Shatrughna, but there is no Explicitness of closeness stated in that incidence.

Comment: @AADTechnical, If Shatrughna had tried to just scold or punish Manthara, then it could be a normal relationship, but he tried to kill her. That shows the intensity of how much he is hurt because of the incidence. Also, if Shatrughna ends his own life by submerging in Saryu river, following his brother, then what more is required to explicitly prove his love for his elder brother.

Comment: Here is the chapter of the Ayodhya Kanda of the Ramayana where Shatrughna tries to kill Manthara: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga78/ayodhya_78_frame.htm

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between God Rama and Shatrughna was excellent.

Shatrughna had killed the wicked and powerful Rakshasa Lavanasura in the thickly forested Madhuvana, present-day Mathura in Uttar Pradesh state. God Rama had lovingly asked Shatrughna to become the ruler of Mathura [Ref: Ramayana 7.76; Bhagavata Purana 9.11.13, Devi Bhagavatam 4.20.56; Brahmanda Purana 2.3.63.186].

Later, when God Rama's envoy reached Mathura to inform Shatrughna  of His decision to leave Earth, he had immediately joined his brother in Ayodhya. Shatrughna's son Subahu had succeeded him at Mathura and his other son Shrutaghati became the ruler of Vidisha in present-day Madhya Pradesh state.

Along with Bharata and Shatrughna, God Rama took jala-samadhi by entering River Sarayu at present-day Guptar ghat of Ayodhya. God Rama was cremated on the banks of River Sarayu, present-day Swarga-dwara ghat [Ref: Ramayana 7.121-122; Skanda Purana 2.8.6; Brahmanda Purana 2.3.63.187].

Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani pgs 65, 67